# Trouble binding 'this' Angular / Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

Basically I'm trying to use this package [pullToRefresh](https://github.com/BoxFactura/pulltorefresh.js) in my Angular application.

The code is as follows

```
const ptr = pullToRefresh.init({
                mainElement: '.dashboard-container',
                onRefresh() {
                    console.log('pulled');
                    // this._service.action();
                }
            });
```

now obviously the `this` is not going to work since `this` now refers to the `onRefresh()` callback function. So my question is how can I correctly bind `this` to use it correctly within that callback function `onRefresh`

now I have tried to just change the callback to an arrow function like so

`onRefresh = () => {...`

but my tslint says `'=' can only be used in an object literal property inside a destructuring assignment.`

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using an arrow function so `onRefresh` does not create it's own scope, like so:

```
const ptr = pullToRefresh.init({
    mainElement: '.dashboard-container',
    onRefresh: () => {
        console.log('pulled');
        // this._service.action();
    }
});
```

Read more about arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: my tslint `'=' can only be used in an object literal property inside a destructuring assignment.` I should of been more specific I did try using an arrow function already I will update my question

Comment: There was a typo in the code I posted. It's fixed now.

Comment: Glad to hear! Accept the answer please :)

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can bind `this` to your callback function.

```
pullToRefresh.init({
  mainElement: '.dashboard-container',
  onRefresh() {
    console.log('pulled');
    // this._service.action();
  }.bind(this)
})
```

Alternatively, you may try this:

```
const that = this;
const ptr = pullToRefresh.init({
  mainElement: '.dashboard-container',
  onRefresh() {
    console.log('pulled');
    that.service.action();
  }
});
```

Comment: My VSCode doesn't like this it says `',' expected`

Comment: Hmm... Ok honestly I am not too sure about that too. How about binding this on the init? `pullToRefresh.init({...}).bind(this)`? Also, I have initially added the `;` at the end of the onRefresh{...}.bind(this). That might have have caused the warning on your VSCode

Comment: No that didnt work either I got a webpack error `ERROR TypeError: pulltorefreshjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__.init(...).bind is not a function`

Comment: I see.. Ok let me update it with the old school way.. Assigning `that` with the reference of `this`